# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и, ссп

*В этом реалити разобьются иллюзии героев(,) и откроются их глаза на правду.*

Comment: Не нужна запятая, здесь общее обстоятельство в ССП (две основы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***В этом реалити** разобьются иллюзии героев и откроются их глаза на правду.*

Предложение сложносочинённое, но перед союзом ***и*** запятая не нужна, так как есть общий элемент.

> **2.** Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
> **1)** Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения: ***Вскоре после восхода** набежала туча **и** брызнул короткий дождь* (П.).

Источник: [Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (Розенталь).